# Page not rendering Properly using MVC and Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

We developing Web Application using MVC and Jquery mobile. Everything works great except Page rendering. When we tested with slow internet connection the styles getting loaded one by one. We analyzed lot but unable to find reason. Whether specified css and jquery order wrong? Now i need to show the page after all elements loaded in dom. Below is my login page code. It render style one by one instead i need to show page after all element loaded in DOM. Please guide Me.

```
@model Highway905MobileApplication.Models.User

@{
    Layout = null;
}


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
    #dvLoginButton .ui-btn {
    font-size:22px !important;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hwy905Mobile</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="~/Content/Hwy905Custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Css/my-custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/jquery.mobile-1.4.2(1)/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/site")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>


        <div class="loginimage" data-role="page" data-theme="none">
            <div class="LoginPopUpPosition">
                <div class="LoginBackground">
                    <div data-role="header" class="LoginHeaderStyle">
                        <span class="LoginHeaderFont">HWY905 WMS <span class="TradeWork">Mobile</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="LoginPoPStyle">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginClient", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off" }))
                        {
                        <div class="ui-grid-a LoginPopUpTop" >
                           <div class="ui-block-a LoginPicImageWrapper"><img src="~/Content/HwyImages/ClientCode.png" class="LoginImageStyle"/></div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b LoginTextBox">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClientCode, new { @class = "myInputStyle", @placeholder = "Client code", autocomplete = "off" , @id="txtClientCode" ,@border_radius="0.1em !important" })
                           </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-a LoginPicImageWrapper"><img src="~/Content/HwyImages/user.png" class="LoginImageStyle"/></div>
                             <div class="ui-block-b LoginTextBox"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserID, new { @class = "myInputStyle", @placeholder = "User ID", @autocomplete = "off" , @id="txtUserID" ,  @border_radius="0.1em !important" })</div> 
                             <div class="ui-block-a LoginPicImageWrapper"><img src="~/Content/HwyImages/keys.png" class="LoginImageStyle"/></div>
                              <div class="ui-block-b LoginTextBox">   @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "myInputStyle", @placeholder = "Password", @autocomplete = "off" , @id="txtPassword" ,  @border_radius="0.1em !important"}) </div>
                           </div>

                        <div class="LoginMessage ErrorMessageStyle">
                            @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="content" class="LoginButtonWrapper"  id="dvLoginButton">
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" id="btnLogin" data-theme="c" class="Button"/>
                        </div>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Hwy905Custom")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ToastMessage")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/ToastMessage")
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would put your custom styles **after** your third-party ones.  This will override the changes in their files instead of the other way around.

I do believe css files are downloaded asynchronously and since you have so many css files, there is a good chance the slow connection is struggling downloading the css files.

I would recommend you bundle the styles together and minify them.  This will create a single file will all the styles in it and then minification will reduce the size of it.  This will allow a single http request to get all the styles instead of many.

Using MVC bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
             "~/Content/Hwy905Custom.css",
             "~/Content/Css/my-custom.min.css"
             //So on and so forth
             ));
```

Please do take note, if the machine is underpowered you *may* see issues with rendering of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add all of your CSS file in the BundleConfig.cs and then render the same in your view

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyNewCss").Include(
         "~/Content/Hwy905Custom.css",
         "~/Content/Css/my-custom.min.css"
         "~/Content/Css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"
         "~/jquery.mobile-1.4.2(1)/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css"
         ));
```

keep these outside your HTML Tags

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Hwy905Custom")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ToastMessage")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/ToastMessage")
```

add

`@Styles.Render("~/Content/MyNewCss")` to them